# Make an id take on rules of other classes

Tags: css

In a CSS file, how can I make an element with a particular id also take on the rules of other classes?

For example, here's my CSS file:

```
div.big
{
    width:1000px;
    height:800px;
}

div.blue
{
    background-color:blue;
}

div#big_and_blue
{
    /* What do I put here? */
}
```

If I want to say that the div with an id of `big_and_blue` takes on the rules of both classes `big` and `blue`, can this be done by referencing these classes in the `big_and_blue` id? I could of course manually write out the contents of the `big` and `blue` classes into the `big_and_blue` id, but this seems rather naive.

Comment: can you not just append ur id to each class you want it to take `div.big, #big_and_blue {` etc

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with CSS alone. What you need to do in that case is give your div those classes in addition to the ID:

```
<div id="big_and_blue" class="blue big">
```

BTW, what you are essentially doing here is called "[Object Oriented CSS](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/)" and can be a useful technique. I wouldn't call it naive at all. It can be a useful strategy especially in a large project being built by a large team that will be maintained over a period of time. CSS isn't the most maintainable of files so it's nice to have the CSS 'chopped up' into a bunch of combinable classes at times.

Also note that the 'big_and_blue' describes the style of the object, rather than what the object is. So it's not a very practical naming convention. I think that's another argument to stick with OOCSS.

On the other hand, you *could* use a CSS pre-processor to handle logic like this such as SASS. That said, if you need to repeat styles across separate declarations in your CSS, I'd argue the former use of OOCSS is a more practical solution.

Comment: Ah yes I know you can just add the relevant classes in the HTML - I was wondering if there is a pure CSS solution, and it seems there isn't. Thanks!

Comment: Can you addClass() twice to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @PeonProgrammer via jQuery? Sure.